# LINQ to XML "System.Exception: Value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am working with LINQ to XML in C#. I have the following code, the last line keeps throwing a System.Exception: Value cannot be null. I can't figure out what the problem is. I've tried everything.
AuthorizedToSign is a List. I was able to perform the same action using a bulky nested foreach loop.
I know for sure there are no errors as far as the XML file itself.
If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

```
BusinessAccounts = (from a in accountRoot.Elements()
where (bool)a.Element("Business") == true
select new BusinessAccount()
{
OpenDate = (DateTime)a.Element("DateOpened"),
Password = a.Element("Password").Value,
Balance = (double)a.Element("Balance"),
AccountStatus = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), a.Element("Status").Value),
//Element AuthToSign has a collection of sub-elements called "authName"
//couldn't get the code below to work
AuthorizedToSign = (from el in a.Element("AuthorizedToSign").Elements()
                    select el.Element("AuthName").Value).ToList()
                                }).ToList();
```

changing `select el.Element("AuthName").Value)`
to      `select (string)el.Element("AuthName"))`
doesn't help.

The XML file has a lot of entries that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Accounts>
  <BusinessAccount>
    <Business>true</Business>
    <AccountNumber>34534456</AccountNumber>
    <AccountBranchID>100</AccountBranchID>
    <AccountName>Elgris Tech</AccountName>
    <CompanyName>Elgris Tech</CompanyName>
    <CompanyID>235</CompanyID>
    <CreditLimit>50000</CreditLimit>
    <DateOpened>2014-12-13T00:00:00</DateOpened>
    <Balance>1200</Balance>
    <Password>1234</Password>
    <Status>Active</Status>
    <AuthorizedToSign>
      <AuthName>Yechiel</AuthName>
      <AuthName>Lev</AuthName>
      <AuthName>Roman</AuthName>
    </AuthorizedToSign>
  </BusinessAccount>
  <PrivateAccount>
    <Business>false</Business>
    <AccountNumber>34534458</AccountNumber>
    <AccountBranchID>100</AccountBranchID>
    <AccountName>Yechiel L.</AccountName>
    <CustomerName>Yechiel L.</CustomerName>
    <CustomerAddress>2sadfasosa, CA</CustomerAddress>
    <CustomerPhone>8-4268</CustomerPhone>
    <CardNumber>304456</CardNumber>
    <CreditLimit>10000</CreditLimit>
    <DateOpened>1994-06-23T00:00:00</DateOpened>
    <Balance>555000</Balance>
    <Password>pass</Password>
    <Status>Active</Status>
  </PrivateAccount>
</Accounts>
```

Comment: And the XML file that you are trying to read looks like ... ?

Comment: Please show the full stack trace, too.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say that `a.Element("Status").Value` is `null` and `Enum.Parse` is throwing that exception.

Comment: I know for a fact that the exception is coming from the AuthorizedToSign line. I tested it line by line

Comment: Jon Skeet, I don't know how to do that, please tell me where to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

According to your xml, `PrivateAccount` element does not have `AuthorizedToSign` node, thus referencing to `AuthorizedToSign` node throws an exception. So, in your case solution will be simple:

```
from a in accountRoot.Elements()
let authorized = a.Element("AuthorizedToSign")
where (bool)a.Element("Business")
select new BusinessAccount()
{
    OpenDate = (DateTime)a.Element("DateOpened"),
    Password = (string)a.Element("Password"),
    Balance = (double)a.Element("Balance"),
    AccountStatus = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), (string)a.Element("Status")),
    AuthorizedToSign = authorized == null ? null : // or new List<string>()
                       authorized.Elements()
                                 .Select(auth => (string)auth)
                                 .ToList()
};
```

Getting auth names with query syntax:

```
AuthorizedToSign = authorized == null ? null : // or new List<string>()
                   (from auth in authorized.Elements()
                    select (string)auth).ToList()
```

Comment: I know for a fact that the exception is coming from the AuthorizedToSign line. I tested it line by line.

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy sorry, added check also for that node (looks like you don't have `AuthorizedToSign` for some elements). Btw instead of filtering out accounts which don't have some elements (e.g. 'Balance') you can provide default value for those elements (e.g. `Balance = (balance == null) ? 0.0 : (double)balance`)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky But the `where (bool)a.Element("Business")` should filter the `PrivateAccount` element.

Comment: that's right, like mike z said, every PrivateAccount has business = false. I'll try your code lazyb.

Comment: @mikez possibly this is a just a sample of xml file, and there exist PrivateAccount which has Business equal to true

Comment: @lazyberezovsky tried your code. No more exception! But, it's still not working as needed. It fills the list AuthorizedToSign with the same number of empty ("") strings as there are "AuthName" elements. But not the value of the AuthName elements. Btw, I removed your ternary null check, and still no exception, so that wasn't the cause.

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy sorry, fixed that also. Reason - when you get elements of `AuthorizedToSign` those elements already will be `AuthName` elements, you don't need ot get `el.Element("AuthName")`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It Works! Thanks so much lazyberezovsky. What was wrong with the original LINQ format? How would you rewrite that lambda expression as a LINQ query?

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy I've added sample with query syntax. Problem was same - trying to get `AuthName` element of `AuthName` element :) BTW if all is OK you can accept answer :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'd even upvote it but I don't have 15 reputation yet :).

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy no problem :) glad that I helped you and sorry for some mistakes that I didn't see from the beginning (I don't have Visual Studio here)

Comment: Just got reputation 16, and you are my first ever upvote! Spasibo druzhishe.